# Tiled Background Image: Can I do that easily with UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have a fullscreen background image that is tiled, i.e. it has to be reproduced a few times horizontally and vertically in order to make a big one. Like in the browsers on ugly home pages ;)

Is UIImageView my friend for this?

Answer (score 105):

If I understand your question correctly you can use `colorWithPatternImage:` on `UIColor` then set the background color on a `UIView`.

If you must use a `UIImageView` you can do the same but whatever image you place in the image view will draw in front of the tiled image.

Comment: Thanks! Well what I want to do is: I have an image file with a pattern, that can be repeated vertically and horizontally. I want to repeat this image pattern on my screen. Maybe it saves some memory.

Comment: If you use the UIColor method outlined you will get your screen filled with the pattern image. There are more complex ways but from your description this should work.

Comment: Hi, this works, but the Alpha of the Image doesn't work. :( Any solutions

Comment: [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:...] colorWithAlphaComponent:...]

Comment: Can we set the colorWithPatternImage through xib rather than through coding?

Comment: @JimThio Nope, you have to do it with code. If I'm wrong someone please comment.

Comment: For years I was doing it this way (colorWithPatternImage:) but Apple has fixed this in iOS6 to add the missing feature. And there's a way to make it work on iOS5 etc - c.f. answer below

Answer (score 30):

To get alpha to work with pattern image, make sure you have the following set:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:aImage];
view.layer.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: The last two lines of this snippet the same thing.

Comment: `view.layer.opaque = NO;` prevails

Answer (score 21):

In [WWDC 2018 video session 219 - Image and Graphics Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/?time=1569), Apple engineer explicitly recommends not to use the pattern color for tiling backgrounds:

> I recommend not using patterned colors with a background color property on UIView. Instead, create a UIImageView. Assign your image to that image view. And use the functions on UIImageView to set your tiling parameters appropriately.

So the best and simplest way to create a tiled background would be like this:

```
imageView.image = image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero, resizingMode: .tile)
```

Or even simpler, if you use asset catalog – select your pattern image asset and, in the Attributes inspector, enable **Slicing** (Horizontal/Vertical or both), set the insets to zero, and width/height to the dimensions of your image:

[image]

then simply assign this image to your image view (Interface Builder works, too), just don't forget to set the UIImageView's `contentMode` to `.scaleToFill`.

Comment: This one didn't work for me when I used vertical slicing with a top inset of 0. Xcode 11.3.1 (11C505). I submitted a bug report for that.

Comment: Hmm, strange, it shows correctly in IB but on the device is shows default `scaleToFill` :/

Comment: Update: This was because devices and simulators apparently cache the launch screen/images (even after reinstalling). It worked on another device.

Answer (score 17):

For years I used Bill Dudney's approach, but iOS 6 has a much better solution. And ... today I found a way to make this work on old versions of iOS too.

1. create the new class "UIImage+Tileable" (copy/paste source below)
2. import this in any class where you want a UIImageView with tileable image. It's a category, so it "upgrades" all your UIImage's into tileable ones, using standard Apple calls
3. when you want a "tiling" version of an image, call: "image = [image imageResizingModeTile]"

UIImage+Tileable.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (Tileable)

-(UIImage*) imageResizingModeTile;

@end
```

UIImage+Tileable.m

```
#import "UIImage+Tileable.h"

@implementation UIImage (Tileable)

-(UIImage*) imageResizingModeTile
{
    float iOSVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if( iOSVersion >= 6.0f )
    {
        return [self resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Nice solution, any idea to use this for iOS 4?

Comment: I thought this worked on iOS 4+, sorry. It definitely works on 5+. Test with 5 and make sure it's not something else that's wrong (I had a few subtle bugs first time I did this). If it works on 5 but not 4, you'll have to write your own tiling code (this takes about 15 minutes to write and debug: make a custom UIView that draws a grid of UIImageViews ... or even better, make a custom CALayer that implements the drawInContext call and splats a raw CGImage multiple times)

Comment: Well, it does not work on <5.0. Nice solution, but I did go for `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:...]` then.

Answer (score 8):

I use a variation of @Rivera's solution:

Put the following in a UIView extension:

```
- (void)setColorPattern:(NSString *)imageName
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]]];
}
```

Then you can set the background pattern in the storyboard/xib file:
[image: Image showing how to set the colorPattern in the storyboard/xib]

Comment: This is a great solution but note that it will not work in a Launch Screen xib file. "error: Launch screens may not use user defined runtime attributes.".

Answer (score 4):

As I really like Interface Builder I created this `UIImageView` subclass to apply tiled backgrounds:

```
@interface PETiledImageView : UIImageView

@end

@implementation PETiledImageView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    UIImage * imageToTile = self.image;
    self.image = nil;
    UIColor * tiledColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imageToTile];
    self.backgroundColor = tiledColor;
}

@end
```

I tried overriding `setImage:` but it seems IB doesn't call it when decoding a Nib file.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of Daniel T's solution. You still need to set the keyPath value in IB. Of course you could be more careful unwrapping the Optional UIImage.

```
extension UIView {
    var colorPattern:String {
        get {
            return ""  // Not useful here.
        }
        set {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:newValue)!)
        }
    }
}
```