# How to AspectFit Background image of UIView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard, aspect-fit

when i set background image as pattern image then image is stretch so, i want to set as aspect-fit this pattern image so, how can do this?

```
 let Image1 = UIImage(named: KeyboardBG_image)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(keyboardview.frame.size);
    Image1?.draw(in: keyboardview.bounds);
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!)
```

Thanks..

Comment: did you set `clipToBounds` of your view as true ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tiled Background Image: Can I do that easily with UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125230/tiled-background-image-can-i-do-that-easily-with-uiimageview)

Comment: Take a look at making a patterned color using `UIColor(patternImage:)` and setting that color to `backgroundColor` of your UIView. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125230/tiled-background-image-can-i-do-that-easily-with-uiimageview

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in `AVFoundation` that might help you create an image in a particular size rect while keeping the aspect ratio. This will calculate the rect size based on the size that you provide, I used a maximum height since the original image is a landscape image.

```
/* create the image at original size */
let image1 = UIImage(named: "Landscape-1276x800.jpg")!

/*
 * create bounding rect with largest possible height based on width
 * this will get you the aspect height for the specified width
 */
let boundingRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

/*
 * Returns a scaled CGRect that maintains the aspect ratio specified
 * by a CGSize within a bounding CGRect
 */
let aspectRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image1.size, insideRect: boundingRect)

/* 
 * create a UIGraphicsImageRenderer to draw the image, this replaces all
 * the  UIGraphicsContext stuff that was used to draw images
 */
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: aspectRect.size)

/*
 * WARNING be careful about the origin points, if the result of the calculation 
 * is an exponential value like 8.988465674311579e+307, then the image won't draw. 
 * To be safe I set the origin to .zero
 */
let img = renderer.image { (context) in
    image1.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: aspectRect.size))
}
```