# Add chess board to transparent parts of an UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimage, transparent

I have an UIImageView, which shows an UIImage, having **content mode** as **Aspect Fit**.

I need to indicate transparent areas of the images with a chessboard.
**How to obtain squares of the same size, no matter the size of the image?**

```
extension UIImage {
    func withChessboard() -> UIImage? {
        var image: UIImage?
        let l = 4

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.setFillColor(UIColor.lightGray.cgColor)
            for row in 0 ..< Int(size.width) {
                for col in 0 ..< Int(size.height) {
                    if (row + col) % 2 == 0 {
                        context.fill(CGRect(x: col * l, y: row * l, width: l, height: l))
                    }
                }
            }

            draw(in: imageRect, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now I have this ( first image being smaller )

[image]

and this:

[image]

**EDIT**, using the solution suggested by Trent, I have obtained this. **I need the tiles to cover just the size of the image, not the whole imageview.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125230/tiled-background-image-can-i-do-that-easily-with-uiimageview) has a clean answer to your solution.

Basically show you how to create a pattern with `UIColor` and set that as the `backgroundColor` of the `UIImageView`.

Let me know if that helps! If not, I'd like to hear why.

Comment: Because uiimageview has `Aspect Fit` for the content, the tiles extend also where I don't have the image. I want tiles just behind the image, not on the whole imageview.

Comment: I've uploaded an image to the question to show you what I have obtained with the solution. But I need the tiles to be just behind the image, not to cover the whole imageview. Like I have on the pics above, but without the resize.